# How to manage user sign in and sign up processes in web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a web api as backend and a mobile app that users can sign up and sign in and call web api(protected) methods to post and get some data from user. I am using Azure AD B2C to authorize and authenticate users with policies. After a user has sign up or sign in, mobile side has an access token and use this token in request to web api.

But in my scenario, mobile side will send username to web api and I will use microsoft graph api to create user with username and default password.(First request is without user token because there is no a user at this time or can be special token that both sides know.) After I created user in server-side I want to get access token using objectId that came response from create request or I want to know how to get access token.

When I have token, I will send this token to mobile and then mobile send requests to web api using access token that come from server.

I wonder this scenario is possible and can be implemented.

Comment: Not very clear, but if I understood it right you want to get a value of a particular item, Access_Token in your case from HttpResponse, If so I don't see it being any different from the usual way you read data from HttpResponse

Comment: Actually it is about how should be set up architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Architecturally, If i understand correctly You want to protect your Mobile app and web api using Azure AD B2C which is clearly possible.

You need to do the following:

- Create a  AD B2C tenant.
- Configure a sign-up or sign-in policy
  Use the steps in the Azure AD B2C documentation to create a [sign-up or sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy). Name the policy SiUpIn. Use the example values provided in the documentation for Identity providers, Sign-up attributes, and Application claims. Using the Run now button to test the policy as described in the documentation is optional.
- Register the API in Azure AD B2C
  In the newly created Azure AD B2C tenant, register your API using the steps in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-api) under the Register a web API section.
  After the API is registered, the list of apps and APIs in the tenant is displayed. Select the API that was previously registered. Select the Copy icon to the right of the Application ID field to copy it to the clipboard. Select Published scopes and verify the default user_impersonation scope is present.

After adding authentication to your web api , you can test it using Postman.For that you have to register postamn under your B2C tenant.
Since Postman simulates a web app that obtains tokens from the Azure AD B2C tenant, it must be registered in the tenant as a web app. Register Postman using the [steps in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) under the Register a web app section. Stop at the Create a web app client secret section.

- The newly registered web app needs permission to access the web API on the user's behalf.

  - Select Postman in the list of apps and then select API access from the menu on the left.
  - Select + Add.
  - In the Select API dropdown, select the name of the web API.
  - In the Select Scopes dropdown, ensure all scopes are selected.
  - Select Ok.

For calling a web api you need to get the bearer token before calling actual web api request.

To make an authenticated request to the web API, a bearer token is required. Postman makes it easy to sign in to the Azure AD B2C tenant and obtain a token. Taking postman as an sample tool.
- On the Authorization tab, in the TYPE dropdown, select OAuth 2.0. In the Add authorization data to dropdown, select Request Headers. Select Get New Access Token.
[image]
- Complete the GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN dialog as follows:
[image]
- Select the Request Token button.
- Postman opens a new window containing the Azure AD B2C tenant's sign-in dialog. Sign in with an existing account (if one was created testing the policies) or select Sign up now to create a new account. The Forgot your password? link is used to reset a forgotten password.
- After successfully signing in, the window closes and the MANAGE ACCESS TOKENS dialog appears. Scroll down to the bottom and select the Use Token button.
[image]
- Now you can test your Web Api with the token, also if you want to save suer information before that you can do that. Also it's the Signup Policies job is to create a user for your when you hit a request.

Hope it helps , Please let me know if you need any help.